# Create a reference to a whole column in Excel through a formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet where I need a reference to a whole column. The catch is that I don't know which column ahead of the time, so I use `MATCH` function to find that out. Once I find the right column I need to reference cells in it.

Two problems stop me from using something simple like `CHOOSE` function instead:

- I have couple hundreds of columns that could be referenced
- I need to reference whole column simply, because the amount of rows is varying as well

Originally I was thinking about using `MATCH`, `ADDRESS` , `INDIRECT`, but `ADDRESS` requires me to specify rows as well. Then I thought I could use `MATCH` and `CODE`, but my formula for columns with multiple letters was buggy.

How do I achieve this? (Reference whole column based on a lookup/match.)

Comment: What is the criteria to match the new column? Are you looking for a column by it's header? A certain value?

Comment: If you can match the header for the correct column, you can use that cell's column. We need the entire function to be able to figure out what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

To just clarify Mureinik's answer a little bit, because it's a good start, for column MyColumn you could use: `OFFSET($A$1,0,MyColumn-1,ROWS($A:$A),1)`

Start at $A$1, and then offset by 0 rows and (your column number minus 1), using a height of ROWS($A:$A) and a width of 1.  Max rows in recent versions is 1,048,576.  You can use a smaller height if you know what the maximum height is likely to be.

So to sum column 3:

```
=SUM(OFFSET($A$1,0,3-1,ROWS($A:$A),1))
```

The answer from sgp667 is not bad, but note that SUBSTITUTE could be a little messy and slow if you are using it a lot.

To reference another sheet, just change the reference to $A$1, so for instance: `SUM(OFFSET(Sheet2!$A$1,0,3-1,ROWS($A:$A),1))`

Answer (score 1):

Number of cells in a column is a constant, it is 1048576 since Excel 2007 and it was 65535 if in earlier versions I recall correctly. If you open `xls` (old format) files it falls back to the old rows count, so you might want to account for that.

So you might reference the range that starts with row `1` and ends with row `104576` like `A1:A1048576`, but using whatever formulas you use.

However, referencing whole columns might make your spreadsheet very slow. Usually it's a good idea to count rows (using `COUNTROWS` once or anything else) and reference the range exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the vague way of asking the question.

I figured out the answer though here is a simple formula that will convert number to column reference: `substitute(address(1,YOURNUMBER),"$1","")`

As I said earlier I am using `match` to find my column number so at `YOURNUMBER` I am using result of the match.

Comment: What I understand is that your function returns a string containing for instance `$D` (column D) if `YOURNUMBER = 4`. But could you explain how you convert `$D` into a range for using it in a formula?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use `INDIRECT` with the second argument set to `FALSE` so that the first argument is a range expressed like `R1C1` (Row 1 Column 1) or `C3` (Column 3).

Example to sum the column 3:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("C"&3,FALSE))
```

But my solution is really slow compared to the one proposed by Sdance. I feel it was something like 5 times slower, after a quick test on 2000 cells containing this formula. You may use this formula if you don't use it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use index & match

```
=INDEX(Array,0,MATCH(Row,Cell,0))
```

You will match the Cell within the Row to find the Column number, then use Index to create an array of 0 rows and the column number resulted from the match, eventually it results in the required column name.

Answer (score -1):

Simple and eloquent

```
=OFFSET(Header,0,0,ROWS(A:A),1)
```

Comment: It's only simple and eloquent if someone understands what's going on here. Your answer lacks necessary contextual information. What is Offset and what are the arguments you're following it with? How can this be applied to a situation where you're looking for Column A? Please use the EDIT button to add helpful and explanatory information to help people apply it to their situations.